# google web fonts looks different in firefox and chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, fonts, google-font-api

I use Ubuntu google font on [this page](http://www.petrdoparlamentu.cz).

```
 <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:300|Ubuntu+Condensed&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

But I have found out that font-weight is totally different in chrome than in firefox.

Chrome:

[image: Chrome version]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hh2y3.png

Firefox:

[image: Firefox version]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/on3Lp.png

The funny thing is that until today it had looked exactly the same in chrome as in firefox. But today
the font in chrome has become bolder. I have no idea why.

EDIT: It seems that the problem occurs only in linux version of google chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I realized that a few days ago I installed the Ubuntu font into my system and that the change in the renderring of chrome is probably caused by it. So I removed the fonts from my system and chrome renders Ubuntu as before.

The behaviour was buggy when It was using the system Ubuntu font. Now it actually uses the webfont and that works as expected.